# Getting Exception while creating AWS ECS Task Service using cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I am getting an error while creating a ECS task service stack using an existing written cloudformation template. The error occurs while creating a ElasticLoadBalancer and it stats as follows:
**Not enough IP space available in subnet-xxxx. ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet.**

I have found out the cause of this error as the subnets I am passing are having less than 8 IP addresses available, But I am not sure about how the error log stats about ELB requiring 8 free IP address in each subnet.

Can someone tell about how to find out the IP address limit and also how to change it ?

Answer (score 0):

After the research on AWS documentation for ELB, I found a reference of ELB limits:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-backend-instances.html

To ensure that your load balancer can scale properly, verify that each subnet for your load balancer has a CIDR block with at least a /27 bitmask (for example, 10.0.0.0/27) and has at least 8 free IP addresses. Your load balancer uses these IP addresses to establish connections with the instances.
Each of the subnet which has been passed in the cloud-formation template should have at least 8 IP address, otherwise the stack creation will be failed upfront. For me the error is occurred because 1 out of 3 subnets has less than 8 IPs available.

Although there are lot of ways to resolve this error but still I feel that AWS should provide a way to change the default limit of 8 free IPs while creating a ELB.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/subnet-insufficient-ips/